# Magento how to remove the From and To price in bundle product?

Tags: magento

I want to remove the "From" and "To" Price info box in bundle product, i found that the block is come from bundle.xml , adding by this

```html
 <reference name="product.info">
 <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

because there is no block name, how can i remove this from the local.xml?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

That comes from the template bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml file. So you better create your own custom module and template file where you can give under what conditions from-to price should be hidden. 
Or simply you can comment the part of code in the above xml file that you mentioned. That worked for me